# Описание Job в GitLab при наведении мышки

Tags: gitlab

Хочу, чтобы при наведении курсора выводился текст с описанием задачи.

Сейчас там дефолтный текст, есть ли возможность его кастомизировать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Название меняется в файле .gitlab-ci.yml, который лежит в корне репозитория.

Comment: название я хочу оставить как есть, а в подписи вывести свой текст, типа: Это процедура для того то..

Comment: это можно сделать комментарием внутри файла yml